# How can I prevent duplicate entries with nested for loops?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists with identical entries but different dates:

```
update = [[45, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 14, 0, 0)], [42, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 14, 0, 0)], [44, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 0, 0)]]

old = [[45, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 0, 0)], [42, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 0, 0)], [44, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 0, 0)]]
```

I want to add entries with an updated date to a new list. The desire output would look like this:

```
updated_urls = [[45, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 14, 0, 0)],
                [42, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 14, 0, 0)]]
```

However with my code:

```
updated_urls = []
for line in alt:
    for l in update:
        if line[0] == l[0]:
            if l[1] > line[1]:
                updated_urls.append(update)
```

I get this result:

```
update_urls=[[[45, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 14, 0, 0)],
              [42, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 14, 0, 0)]],
              [[45, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 14, 0, 0)],
              [42, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 14, 0, 0)]]]
```

I understand that I get this result because of the nested loop, but I cant think of a solution.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you give an example where the desired output is not the exact `update` list?

Comment: @schwobaseggl, yes I will change it

Comment: Won't changing: `updated_urls.append(update)`  to `updated_urls.append(l)` do the trick?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, I just realised that too...

Answer (score 0):

You might be better of using a `dict` than a `list`. Try:

```
d_up = dict(update)
d_old = dict(old)
d_old.update(d_up)  # adds or overwrites entries of d_old
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to store the entries that have already been added to your list and then check against it to prevent duplicates. Here is a simplified example

```
entries= [42,45,42,45]

used = set()

updated = []

for e in entries:
    if not e in used:
        updated.append(e)
        used.add(e)
```